# How to make particles fall like snow

Tags: particles

I'm trying to make a blender animation for Christmas, so I am kind of pressed for time. It is snowing in the scene, so I have watched tutorials on the particles.
I tried it, but it looked too much like rain when I plated the animation. Snow is supposed to lightly drift to the ground, and when I use the particles it looks more like rain and it fell way too fast.

How can I get a  snowy effect without the rain effect?

Answer (score 14):

There are several things you could try, here are a few:

- Try increasing the [*Drag* force](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics/Newtonian#Forces) in *Particle Settings > Physics > Forces* to make particles affected by air resistance:

  [image]
- Decrease the influence of the [scene *Gravity*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics#Gravity) in *Particle settings > [Field Weights](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics#Field_Weights)* to make particles fall more slowly:

  [image]
- Add a [*Turbulence* force field](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Force_Fields#Turbulence) (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Force Field > Turbulence*) to make particles drift in random directions, simulating eddies and air currents:

  [image]

**Result:**

[image: Animated gif]

Comment: You can also use [Brownian Motion](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics/Newtonian#Forces) in place of the turbulence object. It simplifies things a bit and makes large scale scenes easier to work with.

Comment: @CharlesL You could, but I liked the effect of the force field better. To me the brownian motion seemed to make the particles go up more than they should. It's a matter of personal preference I guess.

Comment: How do you use the wind turbulence?

Comment: @JoshuaSlink What do you mean? Just add a force field empty to the scene by pressing `Shift+A` *Force Field > Turbulence*. It will automatically affect the particles. You can change the strength and other settings in the *Physics* panel. See the [wiki for for info](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Force_Fields#Force_Fields).