# Why won't my particles show up in my rendered image

Tags: rendering, particles

This relates to my [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/how-do-i-make-a-realistic-snow-scene-in-blender), but does not correspond. When I render the image  all I get is the objects I put in, but my particles do not show up. The lighting is okay, my snowman showed up along with the trees, but the particles do not. Is it because I paused the animation and rendered that image I paused it on.

Comment: What render engine are you using? How are your particles setup? Could you post some screenshots? (Or better, a .blend?) As it is now it could be caused by a number of things, and we can't do much more than speculate.

Comment: This is too vague to understand what you are asking. Please edit the question and add more specific details. A blend file would be a good addition.