# Looping Video Question

Tags: particles, video

I am making an simple 10sec background animation for an intro video for a website using Blender's particle emitter. The particles are rotating and collisions are turned on and I've used a slight brownian force on the particles to give them a bit of motion.
The scene is simply a shot of the particles using depth of field for visual effect. I would like to loop the 10 sec video for continuous play.

With that in mind, I am trying to make the transition of the loop seamless. I am thinking of using a cross or gamma cross effect to make the transition appear seamless.

Is there a better way for to achieve what I'm after, or will this approach even work?

Comment: Please, check out this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27665/how-to-loop-the-particle-simulation-indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

- If your video sequence has transparency such a png, then the video sequence editor VSE, can layer the video with alpha transparency setting.
- There is always the simple fade to black and start over with alpha transparency.
- The particles themselves can fade to black in a more random fashion with the particle info node.

[image]