# Seamless Loop Animation

Tags: animation, particles, loop, metaballs

I've made a torus shape from particles. I've used metaball for the particles and was wondering if it is possible to loop their movement so it can look seamless if the exported animation is used as a gif?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop the particle simulation indefinitely?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82846/32374)

Comment: another way would be using keyed particles. You can define as many particle systems as you want and so you can loop them by taking the same particle system as the starting and the ending particle system. You can search on yt for keyed particles for a tutorial.