# How to create ambient particles in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, light

How can I create some ambient particles in Cycles, as showed in the following images:

[image]
[image]

If I need to use the particle system, please be very specific, because I don't know how to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29285/how-to-create-dust-floating-in-the-air

Comment: Well, particle systems are not easy to understand so it clearly depends on how much effort you want to put into the result. There clearly is no one button solution that delivers the perfect result (no pain no gain, bro) so without knowing more about your scene it definitely is going to be difficult to describe. On the other hand, I would do most of these effects in post processing.