# Animate floating dust particles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, volumetrics

I wish to create some floating dust particles for animation using a [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29285/how-to-create-dust-floating-in-the-air) here but that doesn't go into the animation part, only the look dev. Could someone tell me how to animate those particles to just slowly float around and fade in and out?
Here is a .blend file:
[image]

Comment: Put a turbulent physics field into the scene and maybe turn the gravity down if it's needed - that will make the particles move. Spawn the particles inside some volume with no initial velocity.

Comment: Use brownian motion in the particles physics settings with some drag and turn off gravity. They'll just bob around in the volume of your mesh then. If you want them to swirl around a bit add a force field vortex

Comment: Thanks for the comments, great solutions both of them.
@Jerryno if I'm not mistaken, you are the one behind the thread I linked?
Could you tell me how to make the particles visible? I thought I will solve it easily but to no avail. I can add the scene file if that's more convenient to you.

Comment: Sure, comment under the linked answer and I'll try to fix or to expand the answer to make it better. You can share the link to your file in that comment, that will help.

Comment: [scene_google_drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B33RFc9jZBV5YVhJRUJDU25iZGM/view?usp=sharing)
@Jerryno Thanks. Here is what I have now.
Sorry, linked answer, just read. editing post now. The linked answer, I don't have a reputation of 50 yet, can't comment on someone else's post. So I put it here for now.

Comment: [Jerryno](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/7777/jerryno) I included the blender file correctly now, without messing with some google drive stuff.

Comment: The particles are visible to me, they are just tiny and hard to see which is good. You may only need more of them. The scatter density is too high for your scene size, you will also need to lower that (maybe something like 0.0001). I created the picture in my answer by shining a light through a slim rectangular slot in black cube filled both with particles and volumetric shader.

Comment: Thanks. And the out of focus stuff, shall I composite or shall I use a DOF object? I plan to move the particles in and out of focus as they move.

Comment: By the way I turned off the volumetric cube's camera visibility and I don't need godrays for this one. The light source - candle - is already rendered separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer post processing dust,  for a still image you would normally just find some free dust particles online and add them in via the compositor. But as for animated particles, I would Google some free dust asset animation packs and add them in the compositor using an image sequence node.

If can't find any online, you can always make your own!

1. Build a cube and icosphere
2. Put icosphere on layer 2
3. Add a particle system to cube and

   - set emission from volume
   - change start and end values to 0
   - set it to emit the icosphere
   - disable emitter
   - mess with size and amount
4. add an emission shader to the icosphere
5. set the background to black
6. Set gravity to a really low value
7. Add a couple of weak turbulence forces to push the particles around
8. After you animate this, you will have generated your own image sequence that you can composite onto any animation

Side note: if you really want to get fancy, you can use a noise texture set to camera mapping to control the strength of the emission node shader, then animate the x and y values on the mapping node to animate light going thorough the dust.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that now, the movement is pretty much fine, but I don't get the same nice results as Jerryno got on his solution. I'm using an array of icspeheres that have a displacement modifier applied, this for the random shape. I increased their size but the image looks like it has fireflies. Note that I'm using a volume scatter box as well, this box is different from the emitter box.

Comment: Try use a noise texture to control both the density of the volume scatter and the strength of the particles emission. This might give a more dust like feeling instead of fireflies, and you could always try blurring the whole image in the compositor. Mess around and you might get a cool result:)