# Create Dust on Camera Lens Blender

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes

I'm interested in creating a dust/flare effect using the Compositor something along the lines of the below:

[image]
[image]

To be honest, I'm still quite new to the compositor, and don't really know where to start with this!

All help is appreciated in advance,

JkyCosten

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29285/how-to-create-dust-floating-in-the-air

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67338/animate-floating-dust-particles

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55551/sun-glow-particles/66995#66995

Comment: This effect doesn't seem to be from dust on the lens, but out of focus particles in the *air*. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32861/how-to-create-bokeh-circles/32863#32863