# (Blender Internal) Ambient Occlusion With Lamp and PNG/Smoke Domain Creates Weird Effects

Tags: animation

I've been having this problem for a long time and haven't gotten to figuring it out. I work in Blender Internal, and I love using Ambient Occlusion. But my projects involve using PNG images with alphas (I use the Images as Planes importer) and Smoke Domains, and usually these need light for surrounding objects to be illuminated by it. So I put a lamp where it is and it creates this weird blue effect. Here are some examples on Imgur:
[http://imgur.com/a/Y9u4W](https://imgur.com/a/Y9u4W)

Comment: Please use the tools on this site to post images, so that they appear as part of your question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29285/how-to-create-dust-floating-in-the-air/30306#30306

Comment: I can't post more then 2 images