# How to animate snow falling in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, particles, physics

In Cycles, I have a simple still life scene with objects resting on the ground, and I would like to animate snow falling onto the landscape and eventually bury the objects.

Semi-new to Blender and open to all suggestions. Is this possible with a particle system emitter? Can I make the 'snowflakes' stop/pile up on the object or ground they hit?

Also, I'm considering using the molecular add-on, which I have never used before and am no expert at physics in general. Please advise.

Comment: look for tutorials on particles and dynamic paint

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REro5vzH2Oo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make particles fall like snow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5049/how-to-make-particles-fall-like-snow)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use a particle system for the falling snow flakes.

You could use a physics sim of some kind to create the "piling up" effect, but I don't think the result would be worth the sim calculation time. Also snow in real life piles up fairly slowly as far as what the eye can see, it doesn't look like a bucket of sand being poured on the ground.

If it were me I would create some sort of mesh object for the snow cover on the ground, and use shape keys to animate it slowly growing higher. The snow particles could just pass right through it or die on contact. This should work unless you need a super macro shot of the snow flakes.